# Coalesce results in a QuerySet

Tags: python, django, postgresql

I have the following models:

```
class Property(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)

    def is_available(self, avail_date_from, avail_date_to):
        # Check against the owner's specified availability
        available_periods = self.propertyavailability_set \
                                .filter(date_from__lte=avail_date_from, \
                                        date_to__gte=avail_date_to) \
                                .count()
        if available_periods == 0:
            return False
        return True

class PropertyAvailability(models.Model):
    de_property = models.ForeignKey(Property, verbose_name='Property')
    date_from = models.DateField(verbose_name='From')
    date_to = models.DateField(verbose_name='To')
    rate_sun_to_thurs = models.IntegerField(verbose_name='Nightly rate: Sun to Thurs')
    rate_fri_to_sat = models.IntegerField(verbose_name='Nightly rate: Fri to Sat')
    rate_7_night_stay = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True, verbose_name='Weekly rate')
    minimum_stay_length = models.IntegerField(default=1, verbose_name='Min. length of stay')

    class Meta:
        unique_together = ('date_from', 'date_to')
```

Essentially, each `Property` has its availability specified with instances of `PropertyAvailability`. From this, the `Property.is_available()` method checks to see if the `Property` is available during a given period by querying against `PropertyAvailability`.

#### This code works fine except for the following scenario:

**Example data**

[image]

Using the current `Property.is_available()` method, if I were to search for availability between the *2nd of Jan, 2017* and the *5th of Jan, 2017* it'd work because it matches **#1**.

But if I were to search between the *4th of Jan, 2017* and the *8th of Jan, 2017*, it wouldn't return anything because the date range is overlapping between multiple results - it matches neither **#1** or **#2**.

[I read this earlier](https://blog.apolloner.eu/2011/10/26/interval-coalescence-sql/) (which introduced a similar problem and solution through coalescing results) but had trouble writing that using Django's ORM or getting it to work with raw SQL.

So, how can I write a query (preferably using the ORM) that will do this? Or perhaps there's a better solution that I'm unaware of?

### Other notes

Both `avail_date_from` and `avail_date_to` must match up with `PropertyAvailability`'s `date_from` and `date_to` fields:

- `avail_date_from` must be >= `PropertyAvailability.date_from`
- `avail_date_to` must be <= `PropertyAvailability.date_to`

This is because I need to query that a `Property` is available *within* a given period.

### Software specs

- Django 1.11
- PostgreSQL 9.3.16

Comment: What you seem to be interested in is whether the `date_from` OR `date_to` falls between the parameters `avail_date_from` and `avail_date_to`. A combination of a the [`range`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/querysets/#range) filter and [`Q`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/db/queries/#complex-lookups-with-q) objects should do the trick.

Comment: @Kendas that won't work with this business logic. I'll edit the post and elaborate

Comment: You are right. The correct solution should (a) detect that the period in question is available within one `PropertyAvailability` or (b) detect that the period in question is available by combining more than one `PropertyAvailability` AND that they are continuous.

Comment: I'm not sure `COALESCE` is quite the best term here: in the context of postgres/SQL, `COALESCE()` means 'the first non-NULL value'. I think this is aggregating ranges.

Comment: Also, I'm not sure that linked post is actually correct: I'm getting incorrect groupings when I attempted to write it against a test set of data, but it's late at night, so maybe that's part of the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My solution would be to check whether the `date_from` or the `date_to` fields of `PropertyAvailability` are contained in the period we're interested in. I do this using [`Q`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/db/queries/#complex-lookups-with-q) objects. As mentioned in the comments above, we also need to include the `PropertyAvailability` objects that encompass the entire period we're interested in. If we find more than one instance, we must check if the availability objects are continuous.

```
from datetime import timedelta
from django.db.models import Q

class Property(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)

    def is_available(self, avail_date_from, avail_date_to):
        date_range = (avail_date_from, avail_date_to)
        # Check against the owner's specified availability
        query_filter = (
            # One of the records' date fields falls within date_range
            Q(date_from__range=date_range) |
            Q(date_to__range=date_range) |
            # OR date_range falls between one record's date_from and date_to
            Q(date_from__lte=avail_date_from, date_to__gte=avail_date_to)
        )
        available_periods = self.propertyavailability_set \
                                .filter(query_filter) \
                                .order_by('date_from')
        # BEWARE! This might suck up a lot of memory if the number of returned rows is large!
        # I do this because negative indexing of a `QuerySet` is not supported.
        available_periods = list(available_periods)

        if len(available_periods) == 1:
            # must check if availability matches the range
            return (
                available_periods[0].date_from <= avail_date_from and
                available_periods[0].date_to >= avail_date_to
            )
        elif len(available_periods) > 1:
            # must check if the periods are continuous and match the range
            if (
                available_periods[0].date_from > avail_date_from or
                available_periods[-1].date_to < avail_date_to
            ):
                return False
            period_end = available_periods[0].date_to
            for available_period in available_periods[1:]:
                if available_period.date_from - period_end > timedelta(days=1):
                    return False
                else:
                    period_end = available_period.date_to
            return True
       else:
           return False
```

I feel the need to mention though, that the database model does not guarantee that there are no overlapping `PropertyAvailability` objects in your database. In addition, the unique constraint should most likely contain the `de_property` field.

Comment: Brilliant solution. Thanks! There's a few errors in your code that I'll edit, but other than that it works

Answer (score 1):

What you *should* be able to do is aggregate the data you wish to query against, and combine any overlapping (or adjacent) ranges.

Postgres doesn't have any way of doing this: it has operators for union and combining adjacent ranges, but nothing that will aggregate collections of overlapping/adjacent ranges.

However, you can write a query that will combine them, although how to do it with the ORM is not obvious (yet).

Here is one solution (left as a comment on http://schinckel.net/2014/11/18/aggregating-ranges-in-postgres/#comment-2834554302, and tweaked to combine adjacent ranges, which appears to be what you want):

```
SELECT int4range(MIN(LOWER(value)), MAX(UPPER(value))) AS value
  FROM (SELECT value, 
               MAX(new_start) OVER (ORDER BY value) AS left_edge
          FROM (SELECT value,  
                       CASE WHEN LOWER(value) <= MAX(le) OVER (ORDER BY value) 
                            THEN NULL 
                            ELSE LOWER(value) END AS new_start
                  FROM (SELECT value, 
                               lag(UPPER(value)) OVER (ORDER BY value) AS le
                          FROM range_test
                       ) s1
               ) s2
       ) s3
 GROUP BY left_edge;
```

One way to make this queryable from within the ORM is to put it in a Postgres VIEW, and have a model that references this.

However, it is worth noting that this queries the whole source table, so you may want to have filtering applied; probably by `de_property`.

Something like:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW property_aggregatedavailability AS (
  SELECT de_property
         MIN(date_from) AS date_from,
         MAX(date_to) AS date_to
    FROM (SELECT date_from,
                 date_to,
                 MAX(new_from) OVER (PARTITION BY de_property
                                     ORDER BY date_from) AS left_edge
            FROM (SELECT de_property,
                         date_from,
                         date_to,
                         CASE WHEN date_from <= MAX(le) OVER (PARTITION BY de_property
                                                              ORDER BY date_from)
                              THEN NULL
                              ELSE date_from
                         END AS new_from
                    FROM (SELECT de_property,
                                 date_from,
                                 date_to,
                                 LAG(date_to) OVER (PARTITION BY de_property 
                                                    ORDER BY date_from) AS le
                            FROM property_propertyavailability
                         ) s1
                 ) s2
         ) s3
   GROUP BY de_property, left_edge
)
```

As an aside, you might want to consider using Postgres's date range objects, because then you can prevent `start > finish` (automatically), but also prevent overlapping periods for a given property, using exclusion constraints.

Finally, an alternative solution might be to have a derived table, that stores *un*availability, based on taking the available periods, and reversing them. This makes writing the query simpler, as you can write a direct overlap, but negate (i.e., a property is available for a given period iff there are no overlapping unavailable periods). I do that in a production system for staff availability/unavailability, where many checks need to be made. Note that is a denormalised solution, and relies on trigger functions (or other updates) to ensure it is kept in sync.